# Recycle Application Pool via WiX

Tags: iis, wix

I'm using WiX 3 to setup my Web Application and most of the cases I'm just installing new versions of the project on the top of the current version, like upgrading the web app every week or so.

I wonder if is there a way to explicit ask IIS to Recycle a given Application Pool via WiX (remove-and-create-again it's not suitable in my case), if not, do we have a way to work around to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a custom action that calls [appcmd.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28WS.10%29.aspx) with the [recycle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770764%28WS.10%29.aspx) command.

In your case:

```
<Product>
  . . . 

  <CustomAction Id="CA_RecycleAppPool" 
      Execute="deferred" 
      Impersonate="no" 
      Return="check" 
      Directory="TARGETDIR" 
      ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:&quot;[APPPOOLNAME]&quot;" />


  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CA_RecycleAppPool" Before="InstallFinalize" />
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
```

Comment: Thanks K. Did you test this fragment yourself? It seems promising, once I have a chance to revisit this issue at work I will test and confirm the answer (hope in the next days), for now, thanks and +1 to show me the path!